# Unity3D scan't find the database

Tags: android, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I am trying to distribute a pre-populated SQLite database with my Unity3d project. It works in the editor and on iOS but not on Android. I have been looking at [Unity 3D + Android + SQLite Examples](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-3d-android-sqlite-examples.114660/) but can't get it to work.

I have a project for testing on Android:

[image: Hierarchy in Unity]

The database is in the Streaming asset. When I run the app on Android I get :

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.defaultCompany.SqliteAndroidTestProject/files/testAndroid.db does not exist
>
> Attempting to create from: /data/app/com.DefaultComapany.SqliteAndroidtestProject1/base.apk/assets/testAndroid.db

I am not able to move the database to the correct asset folder I guess. Full code (I removed the iOS code):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class Test1: MonoBehaviour
{
string fileName;

private static IDbConnection dbconn;
private static string connection;
private static IDbCommand dbcmd;
private static string sqlQuery, dbPath;
private static IDataReader reader;

private int id;
private string first_Name, second_Name;

public Text title, txt1;

private void Start()
{
    ReadDB();
}

void ReadDB ()
{
    title.text = "DB TEST v7";
    txt1.text = "";

    dbPath = InitDBLocation();

    connection = "URI=file:" + dbPath;                                                  //Path to database.
    dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection(connection);                           //creates database connection
    dbconn.Open();

    sqlQuery = "SELECT First_Name, Second_Name FROM TestTable";
    dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
    dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        first_Name = reader.GetString(0);
        second_Name = reader.GetString(1);

        txt1.text += first_Name + " - " + second_Name + "\n\n";

    }

    reader.Close();
    dbconn.Close();
    reader = null;
    dbcmd.Dispose();
    dbcmd = null;
    dbconn = null;
}

public string InitDBLocation()
{
    string _dbPath = "";

    fileName = "testAndroid.db";

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    _dbPath = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/" + fileName;
    Debug.Log("File \"" + _dbPath + "\" does not exist. Attempting to create from \"" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + fileName);

#elif UNITY_ANDROID
      _dbPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,fileName);
      if(!File.Exists(_dbPath)) {
          Debug.LogWarning("File \"" + _dbPath + "\" does not exist. Attempting to create from \"" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + fileName);
          txt1.text = "File \"" + _dbPath + "\" does not exist. \n Attempting to create from\n \"" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + fileName;

          WWW loadDB = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + fileName);   // this is the path to your StreamingAssets in android
          while(!loadDB.isDone) {}
          File.WriteAllBytes(_dbPath, loadDB.bytes);
      }
#endif

    return _dbPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading I still pointed Android Streaming Asset, which does not work. Should be persistent.